# Rxjava2 how to have flatMap emitting items in called order?

Tags: parallel-processing, rx-java2, flatmap, concatmap

Imagining there is Observable A emitting

```
a1, a2, a3, a4...
```

`A.flatMap(a -> f(a))` will emit items in unpredictable order, for example:

```
fa3, fa1, fa2, fa4...
```

How could I get results in order like below?

```
fa1, fa2, fa3, fa4...
```

`ConcatMap` can return the result I want, but it processes streams in sequential order, which is not effective in time consuming.
I need something like concatMap with parallel processing ability. Any solution? Thanks.

Comment: Look at `concatMapEager`

Comment: @zella thks definitely what i'm looking for.
Could you post it as an answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `concatMapEager`, which buffers emission and produce items sequentially.